# Permissions to a nested resource in REST API

Tags: rest, api, permissions, api-design

#### Background

Consider having 3 resources: `reports`, `comments` and `attachments`. The `report` can have many `comments`, and the `comment` can have many `attachments`.

Additionally, `attachments` which are attached to a specific `report` (in the report -> comment -> attachment tree) can only be reached by users who have permission to the specific `report`.

#### Question

Now, I'm a fan of flat URL structures while designing REST APIs, but in the case above I have no idea how could I do this without creating a very long resource like:

`/reports/:id/comments/:id/attachments/:id`

**Is there any way to meet these requirements (permissions) and be able to reach the `attachment` from a flat URL like `/attachments/:id`?**

**or maybe I'm exaggerating and it's totally ok to have these kinds of long resource URLs?**

*Disclaimer: I've created an `attachments` resource (and not `report-attachments`) because there are other resources which also need to have `attachments` - I didn't want to duplicate the structure.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it's totally ok to have these kinds of long resource URLs?

It's totally ok to have any kind of resource URLs.  REST doesn't care how you spell your resource identifiers -- that's kind of the point.  So if you need a log URL because the server needs to encode a lot of information into it, that's fine.

If you are worried about length, you can strip down the semantic hints

```
/reports/:id/comments/:id/attachments/:id
/reports/:id/c/:id/a/:id
/reports/:id/:id/:id
/:id/:id/:id
```

Some of these spellings will be easier for the *routing* framework that you are using on the server, but that's an implementation detail that you control.

There's no rule that says that you have to have the information encoded directly into the identifier; URL shorteners *work*.

In HTML, we also have the ability to construct (some) identifiers from information provided by the client, via a form.  That's because the definition of the HTML media type includes processing rules that describe how the form data is assembled into an `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` representation that is included in the query part.

So you can introduce a similar mechanism into your own media types.

There's also [RFC 6570](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6570), which describes URI templates.  That gives you another way to communicate with the client how to encode information into a URL.

> Is there any way to meet these requirements (permissions) and be able to reach the attachment from a flat URL like /attachments/:id?

Sure.  You just need to be able to use `:id` to look up / calculate the correct permission set, then check the request to see if the permissions are satisfied.

Comment: Thank you for this elaborated answer! :) In the meantime I've realized that I can calculate the permissions on a `/attachments/:id` endpoint, but that would require looking up to the parents. The long-ish way would be a lot easier to implement. Anyways, you gave me enough options to think about so I feel my question has been answered!